# Why didn't Thor take the sceptre back to Asgard?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers-2012

In *The Avengers* (2012), after the war is all over, Black Widow gets a hold of Loki's sceptre. Thor takes Loki and the Tesseract back with him to Asgard.

But why didn't Thor also take the sceptre back with him? Is there a specific reason?

I remember something like Thor saying that the teleportation beam had enough energy to teleport Loki, Thor, and the Tesseract. Was this the reason?

The sceptre is definitely alien. So shouldn’t it have occurred to Thor to take it back with him?

Comment: It wasn't his to take? SHIELD asked really nicely to borrow it for a bit? It not being his makes sense to me - the tesseract was stolen, and retrieved, but the scepter wasn't in Odin's trophy room (IIRC). Thor ain't no thief. /speculation.

Comment: @Yann: I think Thanos gave the sceptre to Loki, although I’m not sure we ever see that happen — Loki falls into the void at the end of *Thor*, and then re-appears in SHIELD’s facility holding the sceptre.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite That's what I was thinking. Although the [marvel wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/Loki%27s_Sceptre) says that the Other gave it to him. It doesn't say when though. I am starting to vaguely recall a line in the Avengers to the effect of "[evil plan], how are you liking that stick I gave you. [evil laugh]"

Comment: @Yann: sure, although The Other is I think that Chitauri guy who, in the Avengers mid-credits sequence, says to Thanos “Well, that didn’t quite go how we wanted.”

Comment: @PaulD.Waite He(?) does seem to be the "give Thanos something cool and foreboding to say" guy. "It would be courting Death". [grins]

Comment: If Thor picked up everything alien that landed on Earth, he'd have quite a lot to carry. I don't think he knew it contained an Infinity Stone at the end of *Avengers*, or he might have taken up more of an interest.

Comment: Definitely related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/88039/12551

Comment: I don't understand this either since during Age of Ultron, Thor has clearly been looking for the scepter. They kinda gloss over that whole thing a bit.

Comment: The Other has a line something to the effect of "You question us? Question him? He who put the scepter in your hand? Who gave you ancient knowledge and new purpose? When you were cast out, defeated!" So Thanos did give him the scepter.

Comment: @Stark07 yes I did glean that post before I posted out here... :)

Comment: @MyCodeSucks who is the Other?

Comment: @deostroll: The Other is the name of the Chitauri that talks to Loki throughout the movie. The one that's next to Thanos.

Comment: @BBlake: “Thor has clearly been looking for the scepter” — really? When?

Answer (score 2):

While I've not read it myself, Marvel's [This Scepter'd Isle](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Avengers:_Age_of_Ultron_Prelude_-_This_Scepter%27d_Isle) is a comic prequel to the new Age of Ultron movie that tells about how and when the Scepter came to von Strucker.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that a reason was ever given. However, in light of the other movies, I have a theory.

After the events in New York, SHIELD took the scepter for "safe keeping". Most likely under Fury's orders to determine its threat and other uses. Given that HYDRA had successfully infiltrated SHIELD at this point, the scepter was "lost" somewhere along the way. Either that, or HYDRA took advantage of the events in *Winter Soldier* to steal the scepter. Although, I believe the first is more likely, seeing as how Strucker had been experimenting on folks for a while. But, it probably wasn't until after SHIELD/HYDRA collapse that it was realized to be missing. This could be done by sending falsified reports about anything going on with the scepter. Again, since HYDRA was at all levels of SHIELD, this would have been fairly simple to do. Especially since the head of SHIELD himself was HYDRA.

Sadly, this would have made a great *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* episode, and they missed the opportunity. There was pretty much no lead up to the fact that HYDRA had the scepter, except for the tiny credits scene for *Winter Soldier*.